# jsPlumb connection, if div was css transformed

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

jsPlumb connection problem, if div was with CSS `transformed (transform: translate(50px, 10px);)`.
Example:
**HTML**

```
<div class="c1">
<div id="a1">
test1
</div>
</div>

<div class="c2">
<div id="a2">
test2
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.c1{
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: #FF0000;
transform: translate(50px, 50px);
}
.c2{
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: #FF0000;
transform: translate(150px, 100px);
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#click1").click(function(){
  jsPlumb.connect({
    source: "a1",
    target: "a2"
  });
});
```

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fara/fc6k8fqn/1/
There are any way to fix/resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using transform use position values instead (left, top, etc..)

```js
jsPlumb.setContainer(document.getElementById("body"));
    
$("#click1").click(function() {

  jsPlumb.connect({
     source: "a1",
     target: "a2"
    });
});
```

```css
.c1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FF0000;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  /* transform: translate(50px, 50px); */
}
.c2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 150px;
  background: #FF0000;
  /* transform: translate(150px, 100px); */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.5.5/js/jsplumb.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <button id="click1">click</button>

  <div class="c1">
    <div id="a1">test1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="c2">
    <div id="a2">test2</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is not solution, if i can change this CSS value, I would not ask the question. I use another library, and this library move object with CSS transform.